# Hide iframe by DIV

Tags: asp.net, xhtml

could i overlap `<div></div>` on `<iframe></<iframe>` please guide

Comment: div is submenu & iframe contains youtube video

Answer (score 2):

Put Ifram in Div and Set style of div Diplay:none; done

```
<div style="display:none">
    <iframe>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

or

**make Iframe width=0 or height=0;**

**Edit**

try set the Z-index property.........

```
iframe { z-index:1; }
div{ z-index:2; }
```

Also check this answer : [How can I position a div over two iframes where one iframe has external (different domain) content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382675/how-can-i-position-a-div-over-two-iframes-where-one-iframe-has-external-differen)

Comment: @MayP : answer before question edited but try to find out solution if any......right now i dont think so is there any... but in new browser version its working fine

Comment: i am trying it in firefox 3.5

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="display:none">
<iframe>
</iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Bint:please read the comment.